# How to know that user belongs to which cognito groups after he has signed in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cognito

I am doing an assignment on AWS and one of the requirement is to list the group names to which he/she belongs.

I am using cognito and I have one group named admin_list and added three users in it. Now I want that when ever any of the user from the list logins then there should be a display message displaying a list of groups in which he/she is present.